# LinkedIn: Javascript Token and validate user in server

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api

I have been reading a lot of questions/answers about the LinkedIn login through javascript login and the validation of the user from backend. But I didn't find a solution that worked with current API.

I understood that the JS token is not the same as the Oauth Token and I don't need to save the token for the future use, I only need to validate the user before the signup on the website.

Once the user is authenticated, I'm going to request the basic profile user and `api-standard-profile-request`

```
IN.API.Profile("me").fields(
        'id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address', 'api-standard-profile-request')
```

The apiStandardProfile returns me an object with an url (like this `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{id_user}`) and an array with headers (like this `name: "x-li-auth-token", value: "name:xxxx"`). I haven't find in the official docs how to use this, but I receive every time an "Authentication Failed" with status code 200.

So, do I need to rewrite the authentication flow with Oauth2.0, or can I continue to use the Javascript login?

Thanks

P.S.: I found and read the old documentation from this old topic https://web.archive.org/web/20141028192415/https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and the only way I found to use the JS token was to use the header oauth_token instead of an Authorization Bearer header when requesting something with Rest API:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,picture-url,email-address)?format=json
Headers {
  'oauth_token': JS_TOKEN
}
```

The JS_TOKEN I'm reading on frontend from **IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token**.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced a lot of issues with LinkedIn APIs, I am recommending you to follow the latest development docs in Linkedin's developer site because LinkedIn had been changed their developer programme [significantly](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) after Feb 2015, so depending upon **the old APIs will be a risk**.

I believe following will help you to solve the issues,

- Use [this link](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console) to explore & test the APIs, including profile API.
- [This is the full list of parameters](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) supported by profile API

If you only need public profile, add this `public-profile-url` as the comma separated parameter in the API.

[https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url,public-profile-url)?format=json](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7E:(id,num-connections,picture-url,public-profile-url)?format=json)

or for **siteStandardProfileRequest**, use following API

[https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7E?format=json)

#### OAuth vs Javascript SDK:

Javascript SDK

- Pros: Easy to integrate, less coding effort, no token management.
- Cons - will not support iOS

OAuth

- Pros: platform independent
- Cons - Token managment, More coding effort